# NSMutuableString modification

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I am new to objective-c and I do not understand completely, why the following is working.
Why don't I have to return the string from the private method so that in the validateAcessCode method the string will be changed?
Is it because the `NSMutuableString` works in local methods with the same reference of the String that I passed to it? Is this the reason?

```
- (void)replaceCharachters:(NSMutableString *)code {
    [code replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"J" withString: @"a" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [code length])];
    [code replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"H" withString: @"b" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [code length])];
    [code replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"Y" withString: @"c" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [code length])];
}

-(IBAction)validateAccessCode:(id)sender {

    NSMutableString *code = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", accessCode.text];
    [self replaceCharachters:code];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just working with a pointer to the actual string. Both methods use that pointer so they access the same object in memory.

Comment: Okay, because i am coming from Java. And if i would pass a String to a method and work on it, it would just be changed in the scope of this local method. But this is probably because java creates a new string reference if i do a replace...

Comment: Right. The Java String is equivalent to Objective-C's NSString, which is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

The `validateAccessCode:` method is being called by `sender` which presumably is a UI object that has a text field. This method is changing the text in the field when it calls `replaceCharachters:`, so there's no need to return anything.